# python click usage of standalone_mode

Tags: python, python-click

This question is about the Python [Click](http://click.pocoo.org/dev/python3/) library.

I want click to gather my commandline arguments. When gathered, I want to reuse these values. I dont want any crazy chaining of callbacks, just use the return value. By default, click disables using the return value and calls `sys.exit()`.

I was wondering how to correctly invoke `standalone_mode` (http://click.pocoo.org/5/exceptions/#what-if-i-don-t-want-that) in case **I want to use the decorator style**. The above linked doc only shows the usage when (manually) creating Commands using click. 
Is it even possible? A minimal example is shown below. It illustrates how click calls `sys.exit()` directly after returning from `gatherarguments`

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--name', help='Enter Name')
@click.pass_context
def gatherarguments(ctx, name):
    return ctx

def usectx(ctx):
    print("Name is %s" % ctx.params.name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctx = gatherarguments()
    print(ctx) # is never called
    usectx(ctx) # is never called
```

`$ python test.py --name Your_Name`

I would love this to be stateless, meaning, without any `click.group` functionality - I just want the results, without my application exiting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just sending standalone_mode as a keyword argument worked for me:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import click

@click.command()
@click.option('--name', help='Enter Name')
@click.pass_context
def gatherarguments(ctx, name):
    return ctx

def usectx(ctx):
    print("Name is %s" % ctx.params['name'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ctx = gatherarguments(standalone_mode=False)
    print(ctx)
    usectx(ctx)
```

Output:

```
./clickme.py --name something
<click.core.Context object at 0x7fb671a51690>
Name is something
```

Comment: oww you are kidding me, did you just try this or was there any logic involved in finding out? Is this working because the kwarg is passed to `click.Command` on creation? Somehow it is passed down to `click.Command.main(..)`

Comment: also if one does something like `./clickme.py asd` this errors out quite bad, because you loose all the error handling from click it seems :(

Comment: I looked at the source, in particular https://github.com/mitsuhiko/click/blob/master/click/core.py#L714, and saw that they pass the kwargs to main.

Regarding the error handling, you do get `click.exceptions.UsageError: Got unexpected extra argument (asd)`. So I assume that you could catch it and print a nicer error message. But yes, you don't get their error handling. Wonder if you could call their error handler... It will always be a hack.

Comment: Well thats true, anyways I'll mark your answer as correct, as it answers my question.